# Update RecyclerView items in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to update the items inside RecyclerView using sending request to API and a timer.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    get_items();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        synchronized public void run() {
            get_items();
        }
    }, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3));

}

public void get_items(){
    Client client = ServiceGenerator.createService(Client.class,getBaseContext());
    final Call<List<Items>> call = Client.getItems("items");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Items>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Items>> call, Response<List<Items>> response) {
            List<Items> items = response.body();
            ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(items);
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatrecycler);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true));
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Items>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

And every 3 seconds the list updates but it starts from beginning.

What should I do to keep the position of the list during update??

Comment: Well it's simple you shouldn't just create a new adapter each time,or what you want to do will be so hard.Just keep your items after 3 seconds get a new list and update the last list(No replace just update) Then use notifyItemChanged(pos) and that's the right way to do this.In that case you won't lose the position.If you got it.Let me know to post it as an answer\

Comment: you are setting adapter in every request . you just need to assign adapter once and add data to adapter in every api call

Answer (score 0):

You should not create new RecyclerView object in every api call. Also you are assigning adapter and LayoutManager with yout RecycletView in each call.

You just need to setAdapter with your RecycletView once and then second time just add new data in your adapter list and notify your adapter to refresh.

Please check below code.

```
private ItemsAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatrecycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SingleChat.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true));

    get_items();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        synchronized public void run() {
            get_items();
        }
    }, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3));
}

public void get_items(){
    Client client = ServiceGenerator.createService(Client.class,getBaseContext());
    final Call<List<Items>> call = Client.getItems("items");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Items>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Items>> call, Response<List<Items>> response) {
            List<Items> items = response.body();

            if(adapter == null) {
                adapter = new ItemsAdapter(items);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       adapter.addMoreItems(items);
                       adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
                   }
              });
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<SingleChatItem>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

> Add one method in your ItemsAdapter.java like,

```
public void addMoreItems(List<Items> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192468/discussion-between-ajay-mehta-rlogical-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code myself.But it must work.Let me know if it doesn't.

```
    final ItemsAdapter adapter = null;
    ArrayList<Items> items = null;
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatrecycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Items>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Items>> call, Response<List<Items>> response) {
            List<Items> newItems = response.body();
            if(adapter == null){
                adapter = new ItemsAdapter(items);
                items.addAll(newItems);
            }else{
                int i = 0;
                for(Item item : items){
                    int index = newItems.indexOf(item);
                    item.stuff = newItems.get(index).stuff;
                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Items>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: by stuff I mean the properties you should update there.